# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 when creating a Array-Element?

Tags: php, arrays, notice

I have a curious behavior which I can't explain. I loop a Array with `foreach` to create a other output-array from it's values:

```
$tabCount = 0;
$mainDivs = array();

foreach($output as $node) {
   $tabCount++; 
   $mainDivs[$tabCount] .= 'blablabla';
}
```

the output is there and seems to be correct (nothing missing). But PHP throws me a Notice:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\WP\wp-content\plugins\test\php\test.php on line 163

`line 163` is the line where I do the `$mainDivs[$tabCount] .= 'blablabla';`

How can that be? I mean, I do create the array element(?)

Comment: `foreach($output as $node) {

   $mainDivs[$tabCount] = 'blablabla';
   $tabCount++; 
}`  remove `.` and put `$tabCount++; ` after assignment

Comment: no need for this `.=`

Comment: `.` is used for concatination not for array assignment

Comment: `print_r($output)` chk this first. u dont have anything in this array.

Comment: I can't understand why that concat-`.` caused the Notice.. but that was it :) .. thank you! :)

Comment: your trying to cancatenate the value with which is not set before so you have to use = remove that cancatenate . @crunchy

Comment: oki doki :) .. thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is used for concatenation not for array assignment.So remove it

So the code must be:-

```
$tabCount = 0;
$mainDivs = array();
if(isset($output) && count($output)>0){ // Check that your array is set and have values so that foreach will not produce error
   foreach($output as $node) {
      $mainDivs[$tabCount] = 'blablabla';
      $tabCount++; 
  }
}
```

Note:-

Reference:-

String concatenation:- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Array:- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: glad to help you crunchy. :):):)

Answer (score 1):

The notice is caused because of your string append operator `.=`.
So PHP will read `$mainDivs[$tabCount]` before writing the new string to the array. That reading is causing the notice

Please try

```
$mainDivs[$tabCount] = 'blablabla';
```

instead of

```
$mainDivs[$tabCount] .= 'blablabla';
```

if it is not neseccary to append the string `blablabla`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your are getting `PHP` `notice` because you are trying to access an `array` `index` which is not `set`. First try to check `$output` array has value or not

try to Check `print_r($output);`

2) Dont use `.` in assigning `array` `value`

Simply

```
$mainDivs[$tabCount] = 'blablabla';
```

There are below ways to create `arrays`:

The `index` can be assigned automatically (index always starts at 0), like this:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

or

```
$cars[] = "Volvo";
$cars[] = "BMW";
$cars[] = "Toyota";
```

or the index can be assigned manually:

```
$cars[0] = "Volvo";
$cars[1] = "BMW";
$cars[2] = "Toyota";
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the dot(.) if your using dot means its act as concatenate .

1)your trying to cancatenate the value with which is not set before so you have to use = remove that cancatenate .

```
$mainDivs[$tabCount] .= 'blablabla';
```

change to

```
$mainDivs[] = 'blablabla';
```

you not need to indexing. it automatically indexing by itself and also it started from zero only .

```
$mainDivs = array();

foreach($output as $node) {

   $mainDivs[] = 'blablabla';

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use concatenation in array assignment.

This:

```
$mainDivs[$tabCount] .= 'blablabla';
```

Should be:

```
$mainDivs[$tabCount] = 'blablabla';
```

One more suggestion before using `foreach()` check either array `count > 0` or not.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$tabCount = 0;
$mainDivs = array();

if(count($output) > 0){ // check the count
  foreach($output as $node) {
    $tabCount++;
    $mainDivs[$tabCount] = 'blablabla';        
  }
}

?>
```